# Grid view showing up as black image in Python OpenCV script

Tags: python, opencv, gridview, parking

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import yaml


fn_yaml = r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Projects\CarParkMan\Khare_yml_01.yml"
# Load the parking data from the YAML file
with open(fn_yaml, 'r') as stream:
    parking_data = yaml.safe_load(stream)


# Initialize lists for parking contours, bounding rectangles, and masks
parking_contours = []
parking_bounding_rects = []
parking_masks = []

# Process each parking space in the data
for park in parking_data:
    points = np.array(park['points'])
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(points)
    points_shifted = points.copy()
    points_shifted[:, 0] = points[:, 0] - rect[0]
    points_shifted[:, 1] = points[:, 1] - rect[1]
    parking_contours.append(points)
    parking_bounding_rects.append(rect)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros((rect[3], rect[2]), dtype=np.uint8), [points_shifted], contourIdx=-1,
                            color=255, thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)

    mask = mask == 255
    parking_masks.append(mask)


# Determine the grid size based on the bounding rectangles
grid_cols = int(np.max([rect[0] + rect[2] for rect in parking_bounding_rects]))
grid_rows = int(np.max([rect[1] + rect[3] for rect in parking_bounding_rects]))


# Create an empty image to hold the grid view
grid_view = np.ones((grid_rows, grid_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
# grid_view = np.zeros((grid_rows, grid_cols), dtype=np.uint8)


# Add each parking space mask to the grid view
for mask, rect in zip(parking_masks, parking_bounding_rects):
    x, y, w, h = rect
    grid_view[y:y+h, x:x +
              w] = np.bitwise_or(grid_view[y:y+h, x:x+w], mask.astype(np.uint8))

# Display the grid view
cv2.imshow('Parking Spaces', grid_view)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm working on a Python script using OpenCV to process parking data from a YAML file and display a grid view of the parking spaces. However, the grid view is showing up as a black image with no visible parking spaces.

The code I'm using is attached above.

I've already tried a few things to troubleshoot the issue, including:

Checking the YAML file to ensure the parking data is loaded correctly
Verifying the parking contours and masks
Checking the grid view to ensure the parking space masks are being added correctly
However, I'm still not able to identify the issue. Why is the grid view is showing up as a black image?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following changes:

1. Set the `grid_view` background color to white by multiplying an array of ones with 255. This ensures that the background is white, making it easier to visualize the parking spaces.

   ```
   grid_view = np.ones((grid_rows, grid_cols), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
   ```
2. Use `where` function instead of `bitwise_or` to combine the parking space masks with the `grid_view`. If a pixel in the mask is True (a parking space), it sets the corresponding `grid_view` pixel to 0 (black). Otherwise, it retains the original `grid_view` pixel value. This effectively draws black parking spaces on a white background.

   ```
   grid_view[y:y+h, x:x+w] = np.where(mask, 0, grid_view[y:y+h, x:x+w])
   ```

Comment: its now showing a white blank grid view without actually populating the grid view with parking spaces

Comment: Whats your sample data? Could you share it?

Comment: My sample data is an yaml file. Here is the picture of the sample yaml file. https://ibb.co/QdDmqGG  @Mehmet Bora Ezer